# Rails 4 & Devise - User's name is not added to database when new user created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm new to the Ruby on Rails environment and most problems I've been able to solve, but I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem yet.

**To provide context:**

- Using rails (4.0.0)
- Using warden (1.2.3)
- Using devise (3.0.0)
- Using rolify (3.2.0)
- Using cancan (1.6.10)

**My Problem**

When I sign_up a new user with **Devise's** registration. The :name field is not being added to the database. *See server output*

**User model** (app/models/user.rb)

:name is included in attr_accessible.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :role_ids, :as => :admin
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

end
```

**User controller** (app/controllers/users_controller.rb).

I've added the params whitelist in order to keep with Rails 4, but this didn't solve the problem.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    authorize! :index, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    authorize! :update, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user], :as => :admin)
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    authorize! :destroy, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    unless user == current_user
      user.destroy
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "Can't delete yourself."
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me)
    end
end
```

**Devise's new registration view** (app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb)

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= display_base_errors resource %>
  <%= f.input :name, :autofocus => true %>
  <%= f.input :email, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :password, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Sign up', :class => 'btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

**Application controller** (app/controllers/application_controller.rb)

I've followed the instructions with regard to strong parameters, and have included the lazy man's approach from [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/rails4#strong-parameters)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_path, :alert => exception.message
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email) }
  end
end
```

**The server output when creating a new user.**

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-16 15:31:20 +1000
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TYp9xOgtdKJI62rUddU7EE1C7FDF5qnmWgGENluzaWk=", "user"=>{"name"=>"John Smith", "email"=>"john.smith@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Unpermitted parameters: name
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'john.smith@example.com' LIMIT 1
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `encrypted_password`
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 16 Jul 2013 05:31:20 UTC +00:00], ["email", "john.smith@example.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$kMfZLiBm6md0zoWXd0esjO/IRHBC72444ABDKcXVhPa6mCco9pIJu"], ["updated_at", Tue, 16 Jul 2013 05:31:20 UTC +00:00]]
   (17.0ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `last_sign_in_ip`
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `current_sign_in_ip`
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = ?, "current_sign_in_at" = ?, "last_sign_in_ip" = ?, "current_sign_in_ip" = ?, "sign_in_count" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 3  [["last_sign_in_at", Tue, 16 Jul 2013 05:31:20 UTC +00:00], ["current_sign_in_at", Tue, 16 Jul 2013 05:31:20 UTC +00:00], ["last_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1"], ["current_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1"], ["sign_in_count", 1], ["updated_at", Tue, 16 Jul 2013 05:31:20 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 94ms (ActiveRecord: 19.0ms)
```

**My Conclusion**

After all this I believe the problem lies in **Devise's** registration_controller, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about accessing the controller and rectifying this, or if this is where the problem actually is. I'm hoping it is something simple and I've just overlooked it.

If anyone has run into this problem or can shine some light on the situation, it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Why do you use both strong params and attr_accessible?

Comment: I used a starterapp generator to create the basic app, it included the attr_accessible lines, and being new to rails, I didn't know any better until now - having learnt about strong parameters through this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rails 4 uses strong parameters.

You have to permit the parameters which you want to pass through controller to model.
in other words direct association to attributes in model through params is now not allowed you have to specify if any parameter value is suppose to pass through controller to model.

You may found some help on this blog:
http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

or as if we consider your problem you can either override the SessionsController for devise or use

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer(:sign_up)
```

more help can be  found here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Answer (score 8):

Adding

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
end
```

to my application_controller worked for me

**UPDATE**

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:name, :email])
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation]) 
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password])
end
```

It looks like devise updated their documents and they want it setup like above.

Comment: :email:password  should be :email, :password

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using bundle, you can access the devise gem to look at the code by:

```
bundle open devise
```

IF you need to override the standard devise controller, you can do so by copying the controller from the gem into controllers/devise/[file name] in your application and it will take precedence.
Note that if you do this you will have to be careful with gem upgrades.

as per the comment before, why are you mixing white listing with strong parameters; you should only need strong parameters in rails 4 and devise 3

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I've had a look but I'd prefer to not make a complete override, as you say, it could be problematic when upgrading the gem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in the application_controller:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) ...
```

needs to be

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up)...
```

slight oversight on my behalf, thanks for the help though.